# UIImagePickerController in iOS 13: Did apple abandon navigation bar customizability?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, ios13, uinavigationbarappearance

In iOS 13 some things seem to have changed in terms of customizing the navigation bar appearance. I want to customize the navigation bar of a `UIImagePickerController`. According to iOS 13 guidelines the code to change an existing navigation bar (in this case changing the `UIImagePickerController` navigation bar background color to red) would be:

```
let imagePickerViewController = UIImagePickerController()
let barAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
barAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
barAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
imagePickerViewController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = barAppearance
imagePickerViewController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = barAppearance
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. In general setting `imagePickerViewController.navigationBar` appearance does not have any influence on the presented `UIImagePickerController`.

The only thing that seems to be working is changing the default appearance of all `UINavigationBars` like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

But this does not allow individual customization and does not allow for extending the navigation bar with your own `UIBarButtonItems` and other navigation bar elements.

I know that there are some questions on StackOverflow about this topic, but none of them has a working answer and none of them discusses if apple has made any changes in terms of general customizability of the `UIImagePickerController`. So here are my questions:

- Did apple remove the option of customizing the navigation bar of an `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 13?
- If not, how do you actually customize the navigation bar of an `UIImagePickerController` in iOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

I tried too, but only `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .red` works just as you said.

Part of `UIImagePickerController` is running on a separate process (`_UIRemoteView`), may be that's why?